# How do I import the data from a html 5 form into php, and in some way make it visible to ensure that I didn't make any mistakes?

Tags: php, html, forms

How do I import the data from a html 5 form into php, and in some way make it visible to ensure that I didn't make any mistakes?

Here is what I currently have:

**HTML**

```
<form action="Input.php" method="post">
Zipcode: <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="Zipcode" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" ><br>
<br>
<br>
Age: <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="Age" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" ><br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="smoke" value="yes" checked>Yes, I use tobacco products.
<br>
<input type="radio" name="smoke" value="no">No, I do not use tobacco products.
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["Zipcode"])
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["Current Age"])
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["sex"])
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["smoke"])

$zipcode = test_input($_POST["Zipcode"]);
$sex = test_input($_POST["sex"]);
$smoke = test_input($_POST["smoke"]);
$age = test_input($_POST["Current Age"]);


print <h2>Your Input:</h2>
print $Zipcode; <br> $age; <br> $smoke; <br> $sex;
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: `$_POST["Current Age"]` will fail and for a few reasons.

Comment: You should also show us the JS that goes with this.

Comment: Haha, that might be my problem, I didn't know I needed java script :p.

Comment: You're also missing semi-colons for `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["Zipcode"])` etc etc. That alone will cause a parse error. Plus, you've no `<?php` tag.

Comment: I am a bit new to coding. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)` is JS ;-) so why include it in your question? You've an answer below. You can ask him now. ;-) enjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="Input.php" method="post">
Zipcode: <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="Zipcode" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" ><br>
<br>
<br>
Age: <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="Age" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" ><br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="smoke" value="yes" checked>Yes, I use tobacco products.
<br>
<input type="radio" name="smoke" value="no">No, I do not use tobacco products.
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?PHP
$zipcode = $_POST["Zipcode"];
$sex = $_POST["sex"];
$smoke = $_POST["smoke"];
$age = $_POST["Age"];


echo '<h2>Your Input:</h2>';
echo $Zipcode . '<br>' . $age . '<br>' . $smoke . '<br>' $sex;
?>
```

Comment: Sooo lol, I figured out how the $age works, but I am still not quite able to import data into php as far as I can tell.

Comment: You will need to make the form action the script which will handle the data. Upon submitting the form, your form values will be available via the POST method. If your script is in the same page as the form, you will need to use isset() to determine if the form has been submitted yet.  If(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

Comment: Also the $_POST['Age'] has been corrected, sorry for the silly mistake

Comment: I would also be sure that you are closing your form tag on the html portion ("</form>" with no quotes). I don't see it in the code you posted and it will affect the functionality of the form. I've edited this answer to reflect this.

Comment: Please be sure to mark your question as answered if this info has helped solve your issue!

Comment: It didn't. I ended up making a program in java instead to do this for the sales rep. Very fun.